# Use of right in standard SQL in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

While running the following code in standard SQL in BigQuery, I'm getting an error stating

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE dataset.dataset
SET New_column = RIGHT(link_id, LEN(link_id) - 3)
WHERE TRUE


Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword RIGHT at [8:18]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substr()` instead :

```
. . .
set New_column = substr(link_id, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression alternative would be `REGEXP_REPLACE(name, r'^.{3}', '')`.

For example, top ways to end names in the USA:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, r'^.{3}', '') letters, SUM(number) c
  , ANY_VALUE(name) for_example
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
WHERE LENGTH(name)>5
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 30
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`SUBSTR(value, position\[, length\])`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#substr) - there is no function RIGHT() in BigQuery Standard SQL

In your particular case it can be just as simple as `SUBSTR(link_id, 4)`

Meantime, i am not sure what you mean by `New_column` - but it must exist for you to use DML's UPDATE against the table

so you final statement will be

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE dataset.dataset
SET New_column = SUBSTR(link_id, 4)
WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: You're right about the new column, that was my mistake. Question edited

Comment: sure, added final statement to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't see here any answer that is an actual RIGHT function emulator in BigQuery. I needed one so I built one(I got inspiration by @Felipe Hoffa attempt):

```sql
DECLARE address STRING;

SET address = '99999 SOME RANDOM ADDRESS, NY 08057';

SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(address, r'.{5}$') AS zipcode
  --this is equivalent to RIGHT(address, 5)
```